# Hadoop NameNode and DataNode plug-ins

Tags: hadoop

I currently have some beginner's level of understanding of the Hadoop ecosystem and the HDFS architecture.

I wanted to understand however some of the following deeper aspects about HDFS:

- Is there a way I can hook into the NameNode execution to identify files being added/modified/deleted from HDFS - Something similar to File system events in Windows?
- Can I write plug-ins that can extend the functionality by performing custom processing present within NameNode and DataNode.
- Data Nodes normally send back a block report for all the blocks that have been replicated across them. Is there a way to extend this data block report to add custom fields or attributes?

Any pointers towards these above questions would be great.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way I can hook into the NameNode execution to identify files being added/modified/deleted from HDFS - Something similar to File system events in Windows?

Yes!  Recent versions of HDFS include a feature similar to [Linux inotify](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html), which allows an HDFS client to listen for various file system events published by the NameNode.  Unfortunately, we don't have clear documentation for the feature on the Apache Hadoop site right now.  If you'd like more information on this feature, then I recommend reviewing Apache JIRA [HDFS-6634](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-6634), which is the main issue that tracked development of the feature.  The design documents and patches attached there will give you an idea of how it works.  Also if you do a web search for "HDFS inotify", I expect you'll turn up some useful presentations and examples.

Alternatively, if you just need a record of all actions that clients have performed against HDFS, then perhaps it's sufficient to parse the HDFS audit log.  This is a file kept in the same directory as general HDFS logs that records a line for most actions performed against the NameNode.  The [log4j.properties sample](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/release-2.7.3-RC2/hadoop-common-project/hadoop-common/src/main/conf/log4j.properties#L136-L149) from the Hadoop codebase shows how to enable this.  Typical commercial distros have it enabled by default.

> Can I write plug-ins that can extend the functionality by performing custom processing present within NameNode and DataNode.

No, there is no general-purpose plugin mechanism.  This is an intentional design choice to avoid the risk of injecting potentially slow custom code into the critical HDFS daemons, which are expected to scale well.  There are a few specific spots that are customizable by implementing a particular Java class, such as permission checks, but it's not intended as a general-purpose plugin mechanism for hooking into any possible event.

The inotify feature mentioned above involves a client connecting to the NameNode and receiving events, and the client can then respond to those events however it sees fit.  However, this does not involve custom client code executing within the NameNode process.

> Data Nodes normally send back a block report for all the blocks that have been replicated across them. Is there a way to extend this data block report to add custom fields or attributes?

The only way to achieve this would be to change the code of HDFS and build it and deploy it yourself, essentially creating your own fork.  This would risk creating an incompatible version that won't work with other applications in the Hadoop ecosystem.  Hadoop RPC uses Protobuf to define the messaging format, and if used correctly it can achieve forward and backward compatibility, but your changes are likely to diverge from development happening upstream in Apache.

If you think you have a feature in mind for block reports that would be generally useful to all HDFS users, then you could consider filing an Apache JIRA to propose it as a feature and get it into the Apache Hadoop codebase.

Comment: Excellent references - thanks for mentioning them :). This really helps to direct my thought process keeping in mind the available features and current limitations within HDFS